# Determining priority for a cyclic compound

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry

I have problem in determining the CIP priorities in (*S*)-ketamine.

[image: esketamine, from USP 2007]

What is the order of priorities for esketamine? Does the carbon bonded to the ring with chlorine have higher priority compared to the carbon bonded to oxygen?

Comment: N  >  (C=O){O,O,C} > C-arom{C,C,C} > (CH2){C,H,H}. The configuration is S. You don't have to go out as far as the carbon bearing the chlorine to make a decision.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible exchange the CH2 group with the C-aryl so that the CH2 at lowest priority is on the back?

Comment: By "back" do you mean draw the structure such that the -CH2- is dotted? Yes you can as long as you don't break any bonds. Make a molecular model and rotate it to see the result. If you dont have a model kit, use a potato and toothpicks arranged as a tetrahedron. Label the toothpicks with the groups.

Comment: Silvia95: You can visualize (S)-ketamine here as the last item in the first group. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSEZ14161.html